# CAS Client for Magento

Tags: magento, single-sign-on, cas

We have shell web application which shows different applications allowed to logged in user. We use Drupal/CAS server to authenticate/log in  to this application. Once user is logged in, he/she does not have to login to other applications. Same credentials are passed to other applications. Now we want to integrate Magento in this application, say user1 logs into our shell web application, he/she will see link to magento store, when he clicks on it, it will automatically get logged into Magento site and don't have to enter user id/password.

Our authentication service uses CAS server under Drupal.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but what specifically is the question?

Comment: I want to start magento session in another tab/window without user putting his/her credentials. i am using CAS server in Drupal for authenticating multiple applications. I want to use Magento to use same service to authenticate users.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that Magento natively supports CAS nor that anyone as built a native library. Magento seems to be able to be connected to CAS only through an additional library: [Magento Documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/intergrating_3rd_party_cms/connecting_through_zend-auth_to_tikiwiki)